# CUDA/OpenGL InterOp: Using Grayscale Image as Texture with

Tags: opengl, cuda

I am using CUDA OpenGL interop for a grayscale image. I have a grayscale image of size `imgW x imgH` on the CPU. I intend copy the image to the GPU memory and later use CUDA to update it. Meanwhile, OpenGL should render the updated image.

I have the following code that works:

```
//img: a grayscale image on the CPU
//Allocate Buffer using OpenGL
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, __bufferIdMain);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, imgW * imgH * 4, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY); //Must allocate 4 times the memory required, otherwise don't work
glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, 0);

checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&__cudaVboResourceMain, __bufferIdMain, vbo_res_flags));

//Copy grayscale image to GPU memory
checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsMapResources(1, &__cudaVboResourceMain, 0));
checkCudaErrors(cudaGraphicsResourceGetMappedPointer((void ** ) &dptr, &num_bytes, __cudaVboResourceMain));
cudaMemcpy(dptr, img, imgW * imgH, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //CUDA can use dptr

//Generate Texture from Buffer
glGenTextures(1, &__textureIdMain);
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, __textureIdMain);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, imgW, imgH, 0, GL_LUMINANCE, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, NULL);
```

My display function, along with the timer function just draws the texture. The code works, but my only issue is, I need to use 4 times more memory when calling `glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, imgW * imgH * 4, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY);`. I tried to use only `imgW * imgH` instead of `imgW * imgH * 4` but does not render the image. Note that, I only copy `imgW * imgH` bytes to the GPU memory. Is there a way to use less memory on the GPU to render the image?

Comment: Can you provide more data such as the configuration of the bufferIdMain and the cudaVboResourceMain (does VOB stand for Vertex Buffer Object ?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I found the answer. The main problem was, the `GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER` was aligning with 4 bytes. I added the following line before creating the buffer. Now I can just allocate the required memory.

```
glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER, imgW * imgH, 0, GL_DYNAMIC_COPY); // Now only using just the necessary amount of memory
```

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe, you are operating on a Vertex Buffer Object, or at least the API believes so. You want to use `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage`, described [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#opengl-interoperability), indeed, the obe component texture is available:

> The array can also be read and written via cudaMemcpy2D() calls.
>   cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage() supports all texture formats with 1, 2,
>   or 4 components and an internal type of float (e.g., GL_RGBA_FLOAT32),
>   normalized integer (e.g., GL_RGBA8, GL_INTENSITY16), and unnormalized
>   integer (e.g., GL_RGBA8UI) - See more at:
>   http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#opengl-interoperability

The example provided in the documentation is for vertices, indeed in a 2D map, but vertices still.

Comment: I was using the GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER to register. I used something like `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterBuffer(&__cudaVboResourceMain, __bufferIdMain, vbo_res_flags)` to register the buffer. However, the problem I was facing was due to alignment.  I will try to use the `cudaGraphicsGLRegisterImage` in future.